# Using Knockout & Typescript. How can I change the value of an Observable from its subscription?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, observable, subscribe

Using Knockout & Typescript. How can I change the value of an Observable from its subscription?

I'm refactoring a KO old code using Typescript, and I found this piece of code that subscribes to an observable and is updating it using "this" which is not possible with TypeScript.

```
let utils = new Utils();

utils.subscribeFilterAlphanumeric = function(val){
    var newVal = utils.filterAlphanumeric(val);
    this(newVal); 
    // "this" in regular JS is the observable
    // "this" in Typescript is the Class "Utils"
};

myObservable = ko.observable();
myObservable.subscribe(utils.subscribeFilterAlphanumeric , myObservable);
```

Any suggestion how to make this work in Typescript?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, you have control over what "this" is by using => or not.

```
class x {
    public myObservable: KnockoutObservable<any>;

    constructor(){
        this.myObservable = ko.observable<any>();
        this.myObservable.subscribe(function(val){
            // Not using => this remains myObservable
            var newVal = utils.filterAlphanumeric(val);
            this(newVal); 
        })
    }
}
```

Should work OK

Comment: In this case yes, but I don't know exactly why but Typescript treats the "this" differently if you are in a function than arrow function.

Comment: It is quite instructive to look at the .js code generated by the TypeScript compiler for callbacks with and without the => notation. If you use =>, a "_this" member is generated and substituted in the callback code. I think you will see the solution to you particular case if you look there.

Answer (score 0):

Ko.Extenders it was a good solution

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

I created:

```
ko.extenders.filter = function (target, filterType) {
    if (filterType == "number") { 
        wUtils.observableSubscribeFilterNumber(target);
    }
    return target;
};
```